Is it possibe to disable all signing/verification in spring-security-saml2-service-provider?
For the purposes of testing, I would like to run SAML exchanges without any signatures/encryption.
In the previous spring-security-saml2-core, this could be done via the setRequire*Signed(false) methods on ExtendedMetadata. However, there appears to be no equivalent in RelyingPartyRegistration or similar.
Indeed, I get this exception when just loading metadata:
org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: Metadata response is missing verification certificates, necessary for verifying SAML assertions
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.OpenSamlMetadataRelyingPartyRegistrationConverter.convert(OpenSamlMetadataRelyingPartyRegistrationConverter.java:97)

Is there a way to disable it, or do I need to generate some keys and sign everything in my test data?
